# Can malware be the source or 600% load on 8-core i7 processor with nothing in Activity Monitor nor `top`?

Tags: cpu, malware

My Mac suddenly started showing a heavy processor load, i.e. 600% or more.

When I checked in iStat Menus, Activity Monitor and `sudo top`, no process was shown to consume more than 10%.

Should I worry about malware?

```
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,3
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2,6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
```

[image: Pic as it happened]

Comment: The screenshot of AM only shows your processes. Enable In the Activity Monitor menubar: View -> All processes. Please also add the medium CPU core and the Palm Rest and/or hard drive temperature (as shown in iStat Menus)

Comment: Try running a scan with Avast or BitDefender!